# Сравнение имён по их части (или производной)

Tags: python, алгоритм

У меня есть 2 имени, которые нужно сравнить. Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как написаны эти 2 имени. Там может оказаться "Дмитрий" и "Dmitry", может "Димочка" и "Димон", может одно из имён будет написано с ошибкой. Мне нужно сравнить их и убедиться, что это одинаковые имена (или нет). Для этого я придумал такой алгоритм:

1. Транслитом переводим имена (если в них попадаются не кириллические символы)
2. Делаем стемминг по имени
3. Проходим по получившимся именам алгоритмом по поиску расстояния Левенштейна (кол-во ошибок задаём 2)

Но в этом алгоритме возникла такая проблема. Предположим, мне прилетел "Дима" и "Дмитрий". Транслитом здесь переводить ничего не нужно. После стемминга мы получим "дим" и "дмитр"... и, как вы понимаете, расстояние  Левенштейна скажет, что это разные имена. Из этого вопрос: как понять, что "дима" = "дмитрий" или "дим" = "дмитр"? Может существуют python библиотеки для такого поиска? Или есть какой-то алгоритм? Или мой алгоритм полностью неверен?

Comment: Ещё можно word embeddings привлечь. Но толку то? Вопрос в том - зачем вам это всё? Скорее всего для того, чтобы однозначно сопоставить имена людей, вам нужна будет ещё какая-то информация об этих людях. Ибо даже при полном совпадении имени и фамилии у вас нет гарантии, что один Иван Иванович Иванов и другой Иван Иванович Иванов - это два одинаковых человека. Может это два разных человека разного возраста и живущих в разных концах страны. И что дальше?

Comment: С сокращенными и уменьшительно-ласкательными вы порядком намучаетесь. Представьте себе имя "Алексей". Вот некоторые варианты: `Алексейка, Алёха, Лёха, Алёша, Лёша, Алёня, Лёня, Алёка, Алека, Лёка, Лека, Лёля, Аля, Алюня, Люня, Лексейка, Лекса, Лекся, Лёкса, Лёкся`. И это только на кириллице! Думаю лучшим вариантом будет автоматически гуглить `Алексей варианты` и парсить результаты...

Comment: Есть вариант парсить сайты, где есть много вариантов имени  типа http://peoplenames.ru/ С помощью таких сайтов можно вылавливать подобные варианты, но в целом мой вопрос ещё актуален

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, наверняка понадобится словарь или префиксное дерево с парами `<полное_имя:неполное_популярное_имя>`. После обработки полного имени можно использовать прежний алгоритм.

Было бы ещё неплохо находить длину наибольшей общей подстроки между именами. А потом делать выводы, основываясь хотя бы на этих двух метриках.

Кстати, насчёт имён Дима и Дмитрий: в данном случае здесь лучше сработает модификация расстояния Левенштейна (Дамерау), поскольку нетрудно заметить, что буквы `и` и `м` меняются местами.